# DDNS (NoIP) VNC cant connect

Tags: networking, router, dns, port-forwarding, vnc

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 and I was able to get x11vnc up and running on my local network. I wanted to extend this for remote access. Please see the steps I have taken below:

- Setup x11vnc (Can confirm running on port 5900)
- Setup Noip (created hostname and downloaded DUC and can confirm running)
- Setup port forwarding on router and can confirm the port is open (when I do this I get a message from x11vnc which I take as a good sign)
- Installed GUFW (though I have "Off" because otherwise port is closed for some reason regardless of rule to allow incoming connection to port 5900)
- Can confirm router firewall is not blocking port 5900 (or at least it doesn't say it is)

So what I can't understand is why I can't connect VNC when I feel like everything is in order. I can't connect using my public/external ip OR ddns but when I enter the ddns in the URL of a browser I can access my router page (which I don't like at all and would much prefer to disable if this is possible)

I have used two different clients to try to connect to the server just to make sure it wasn't a client issue as well. Please help, thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Any thoughts on using a Hamachi VPN to VNC?

Comment: Are you testing the connection from within your network or from an external network?

Comment: Well the noip port status tool pulls your external ip automatically so I didn’t realize it would make a difference to test from an external network, would it?

Comment: It may, due to something known as [NAT Loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback).  Without that feature your router won't process port forwards for traffic that is internal but uses the external IP.

Comment: So you are saying that the port might not actually be open? Just appears to be? What is the solution in that case?

Comment: Kind of.  In effect, the port is open but only to traffic the originates from outside your network.  The router I used back in the early 2000's had this issue.  My web server could be accessed by my LAN devices only by it's internal LAN IP, not the public IP.  Using the public IP worked just fine for external devices though, such as from a friends house.

Comment: Hmmm well that’s good news actually because I have a working setup on the internal network and this remote setup is for exactly that (accessing from an external network). I will try to access from an external network and see if it is working as soon as I can get back to my computer in a couple days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to NAT Loopback -- Thanks @kicken

Answer (score 0):

During the setup wizard on NO-IP's homepage, there is a little tool to check if the port is really open with a port scan for the port you enter. Via this method you can verify if your firewall is not blocking port 5900.
Next thing: is the NO-IP-DUC really providing information about a service on port 5900 **AND** 5800 according to the official setup guide for VNC with NO-IP?

You will need to forward and configure both ports
[Remote Control Using VNC And No-IP](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/remote-control-using-vnc-and-no-ip/)

Comment: Port-check-output: Success!   I can see your service on ##.###.##.### on port (5900)
Your ISP/Router/Firewall is not blocking port 5900.

Comment: If I run `noip2`: One noip2 process is already active,
and the multiple instance flag (-M) is not set.
Which is why I thought it was working. How would I check for the service itemization?

Comment: I get a connection timeout on port 5800 though forwarding is enabled

Comment: Now I get a connection-refused (consistently)

Comment: not sure if this is because x11vnc doesn't listen for 5800?

Comment: `lsof -i :5800` outputs nothing

Comment: I think vnc client is using port 65320; I adjusted forwarding settings accordingly and same result... I say this because `lsof -i :5900` gives `x11vnc  68863 butters-ubuntu    9u  IPv4 2579705      0t0  TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
x11vnc  68863 butters-ubuntu   10u  IPv6 2579706      0t0  TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
x11vnc  68863 butters-ubuntu   11u  IPv4 3302419      0t0  TCP sterlingbutters:5900->10.0.0.237:65320 (ESTABLISHED)
`